# Not able query the table in mysql database , mysqli_query returns false

Tags: php, mysql

I have just started learning php and i am trying to set up connection to local mysql db
I have pasted the code that i am trying to run.

I am getting $result = false
and i reach else part --" No return"
In the image attached , there is a table called "table" under db test, and i have 3-4 entries as well

[image: image-snapshot]

Can someone take time to help me understand whats going wrong here ?

thank you !!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>  
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
         <?php
            $link = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','test'); 
            $query = "select * from 'table' " ;


            $outputDisplay = "";
            $myrowcount = 0;
                if (!$link) 
                { 
                    die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_error()); 
        } else 
            {
                echo 'Connection OK'; 
                print ($query);
                $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

                if($result)
                {
                                        $numresults = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                    printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", $numresults);
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "No return";
                }
                mysqli_close($link); 
            }
         ?>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli_query()` returns false because something wrong has  happened in your query..Here your problem is with the single quotes..Instead of single quotes you should use back-ticks like

```
        $query = "select * from `table` " ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , After reading this , i searched a little more about back-ticks , so now as i understand Backticks are only needed when table name or column name is a MySQL reserved word.  Am i right ?? or is there something more to it ? .. I needed back-tick because my table name was "table" ??

Comment: @swatisaoji yes what you found was right.backticks are used when there is a reserved work as a column or table name ..:)

Answer (score 4):

```
        $query = "select * from 'table' " ;
```

You can't put table names in single-quotes. Single-quotes are for string literals and date literals.

You may put table names in back-ticks:

```
        $query = "select * from `table` " ;
```